# Spring boot not not working after adding dependency of actuator

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to use Actuator. The problem is that when i use version 2 or above, server starts to fail. If i use version 1 less than 2 server starts properly but, i do not get end points like /actuator etc. Please help. Really stuck in it.

Pom file looks like this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>

    <!--            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>-->
</dependency>


 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
  </dependency>
    <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Application properties

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

Exception when application start fails

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
10-06-2020 17:59:44.274 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.business.api.throttler.ThrottlerApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/context/ConfigurableReactiveWebApplicationContext not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:646)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.lambda$processDeferredImportSelectors$2(ConfigurationClassParser.java:566)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.bus.catalog.CatalogApplication.main(CatalogApplication.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/context/ConfigurableReactiveWebApplicationContext not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:221)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:362)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:636)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/context/ConfigurableReactiveWebApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.OnManagementPortCondition.isWebApplicationContext(OnManagementPortCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.OnManagementPortCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnManagementPortCondition.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ConfigurableReactiveWebApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53116', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Did you read the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)? And as a note: Since you have set the <parent>, you no longer have to specify a version for the spring boot starter dependencies.

Comment: It is wrong to set a version for actuator if you are using the parent. Also micrometer-core etc. is already handled by the parent...so no version definition needed.

Comment: yeah, but if i not mention the version application does not run. It's due to adding dependency of Actuator. If i mention version 1.x.x with actuator, application runs but don't get actuator end points.

Comment: Don't use a version or at least never mix versions of a framework. Fix the exception you get, mixing it with jars from a different versions isn't fixing things but will lead to other issues. So instead of showing only the versions show the exception you get.

Comment: I have added the exception. please help

Answer (score 1):

so your question was a bit messy until I haven't seen your reply on one of the comments under your question.

> "yeah, but if i not mention the version application does not run. It's due to adding dependency of Actuator. If i mention version 1.x.x with actuator, application runs but don't get actuator end points."

So, the thing is that your pom.xml should look like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Notice that ***I haven't defined the versions "manually"*** because I let the parent starter pom do it correctly instead of me. :)

---

Another problem that I surmise that you have based on your reply ("not mention the version application does not run")

Sounds like you weren't able to get the dependency. I mean you haven't put the error message here for that case, but I assume that you should run
`mvn -U clean package` to re-download the dependencies and get the right ones.

If you use IDEA you should run a "reimport/refresh" on pom.xml. :)

I hope it helps!

---

update:
I noticed also that you include both micrometer-core and micrometer-registry.

Completely unnecessary!!

Please always look at the included dependencies graph.

You can easily do that with for example "Dependency Analyzer" plugin in IDEA. 
It will help you to see the duplicated inclusions.

[image: Dependency Analyzer]
For example on this picture, you should see that micrometer-core dependency comes with the actuator and the micrometer-registry thus you shouldn't include it "manually". :)